# How to show count of checkboxes botton in a label

Tags: ios, uitableview, checkbox

i am making an app in which i am  using checkboxes in uitableview cell. Now i am stuck on it how can i show count of selected checkboxes in a label. like i check one box then in label "1 checkbox selected" will shown and if i select 2 check boxes then in label "2 checkbox selected" will shown how it can be done any idea? below is my code where i am handling my checkbox button:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    static NSString *tableviewidentifier = @"cell";
    tablecellTableViewCell *cell= [self.activitiesTableView_ dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:tableviewidentifier];

    if(cell==nil)
    {
        cell = [[tablecellTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:tableviewidentifier];
    }

    UILabel *valuedate = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:11];
    UILabel *msg = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:12];
    UILabel *date = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:13];
    UILabel *time = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:14];
    [valuedate setText:@"Demo"];
    [msg  setText:@"How are You?"];
    date.text=@"14/07/2014";
    time.text=@"A 08:16";


    // [cell.textLabel setText:activityModel.userName];
    valuedate.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"SegoeUI" size:15];
    msg.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"SegoeUI-light" size:10.0];
    date.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"SegoeUI-light" size:9];
    time.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"SegoeUI-light" size:9];



    if ([self.checkimageArray containsObject:[self.lblArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]])
    {
         [cell.button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tick.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        //[cell.button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"uncheck.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    }
    else
    {
         [cell.button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"uncheck.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    }

    cell.button.tag=indexPath.row;
    [cell.button addTarget:self action:@selector(checkButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];



    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 viewDidLoad

 yourTableView.allowsmultiselection=YES;

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   UITableViewCell *cell=[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]; 
   [cell.btn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"selected-24.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
   NSArray *arr=[tableView indexPathsForSelectedRows];
   lbl.textLabel.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[arr count] ];
}
in deselect 
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   UITableViewCell *cell=[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]; 
   [cell.btn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"unselected-24.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
   NSArray *arr=[tableView indexPathsForSelectedRows];
   lbl.textLabel.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[arr count] ];
 }
```

Comment: increase counter like Nsinteger i ; and then i++?

Comment: and how can i store count ??

Comment: static int i=0;  after @implementation YourViewController

Comment: and how can i store my count in i variable ?

Comment: this is the main thing how count of checkboxes are stored in this variable ?

Comment: you may also want to change image on  check,uncheck?

Comment: yeah i also want to but will you please tell how can i store the count  ?

Comment: take that static int counter=0; in .m file and increase counter on that method

Comment: like int counter =0; then i increase in void(checked) method like this
i++?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65738/discussion-between-mishal-awan-and-johny-kumar).

Answer (score 0):

Take a NSMutableArray for selelcted buttons.when you select particuler button at that time add that indexpath.row value to the array.And when you delselect the button at that time check wheateher that indexpath.row value present in that array or not ,if yes then find the index of that object and remove that object from the array.

```
if([array containsObject:@"value"]){
        int n=[array indexOfObject:@"value"];
        [array removeObjectAtIndex:n];

    }
```

Now check the count of array as [array count];